# Why is my page load over 1.5 second with that little data in next.js with prisma?

Tags: reactjs, express, next.js, prisma

**Context:**

I'm building a reddit clone right now. I'm fetching a list of a subreddit posts in `getServerSideProps`. This function makes an api call to my prisma database (hosted on Amazon AWS - PostgreSQL).

Here is the working live example (just select a subreddit in the dropdown). Next.js has some posts, learnprogramming hasnt: https://reddit-clone-teal.vercel.app/

**Here is the api:**

```
const handler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  try {
    const sub = await prisma.subreddit.findUnique({
      where: { name: String(req.query.name) },
      include: {
        posts: {
          include: { subreddit: true, user: true },
        },
        joinedUsers: true
      },
    });

    console.log("here is the sub", sub);

    if (!sub) {
      return res.status(500).json({ error: "No sub was found with this name" });
    }

    res.json(sub);
  } catch (e) {
    res.json(e);
  }
};
```

So nothing too crazy right (it's 3 posts total)? Or am I including too much in the call?
Anyway when I transition to a subreddit and this function runs (there are currently 3 dummy posts in the db) it takes sometimes 1.5 - 2 seconds after the page has loaded in.
With such little data this should be much less loading time am I right?

I'm using `swr` and here is how a subreddit page looks like:

**First the `getServerSideProps` function:**

```
export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
  const url = `${process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL}/api/subreddit/findSubreddit?name=${ctx.query.sub}`;
  const fullSub = await fetchData(url);

  return {
    props: {
      fullSub,
    },
  };
}
```

**And then on the page itself:**

```
const { data: fullSub, error } = useSWR(
    `/api/subreddit/findSubreddit?name=${sub}`,
    fetchData,
    {
      initialData: props.fullSub,
    }
  );
```

Here a screenshot of Vercel Analytics:

[image]

It also kinda loads it everytime (going from one subreddit to another), although I'm caching it with `swr`. I think I'm doing something wrong. It's kinda faster then the first transition from subreddit A to subreddit B but shouldn't it be instant when nothing has changed? Isn't that the advantage of using `swr` or am I missing something again?

Can you figure it out? Any ideas why this might long load and not cache?

Full link to my repo: https://github.com/SelfDevTV/reddit-clone

Comment: I can see your requests taking a substantial amount of time (sometimes over 1s) so I suspect the delay comes from the `prisma` database calls.

Comment: Yep it does but I don't know why, thats why I created this question. Am I fetching too much or including too much in my api call?